# ¿Como crear boton para subir archivos en joomla?

Tags: html

estoy creando una pagina web con joomla para una empresa de constuccion, necesito hacer el tipico boton de examinas, selecionar un archivo del ordenador y que el usuario pueda subir ese archivo, ya sea en una base de datos de phpmyadmin o simplemente en alguna carpeta de joomla, Basicamente se va a utilizar para que la gente pueda subir curriculums a la pagina web. Muchas gracias con antelacion.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file

Comment: Estás usando los formularios de Joomla o alguna extensión en particular? Ayudaría mucho si adjuntas una captura de pantalla de lo que tienes en el momento.